# How to get \dotfill dots to line up nicely

Tags: dotfill

I have the following code example that builds a table of contents like feature

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand \dotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ 1.0em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{5.5in}r}
        Apple\dotfill & 1\\
        Banana\dotfill & 12\\
        Orange\dotfill & 140\\
        Watermelon\dotfill & 180\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Notice the dots are misaligned. How can I get them aligned?

Comment: `\leaders` instead of `\cleaders`.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!